# What is this bee/wasp nest?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, wasps

Perhaps this is a tropical wasp. Can you identify it? Is it artificial?

[image]

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: What is your location? Also, what makes you think that this is a wasp nest?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know where it's from: I was researching animal nests, and I found the pic on a random trivia page. Then I searched google images, there are only 3-4 HD copies of the photo and I couldn't find the origin of it.

Comment: FYI this appears to have originated from reddit user Crabcaked from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/2hjx10/a_friend_left_a_glass_bowl_outside_and_a_wasp/). I added more pictures to your question here from that post

Comment: I do not believe that this is a wasp nest. What makes you think that this nest belongs specifically to a wasp species?

Comment: awesome, well spotted. I thought that reddit was joke website. I wrote that it was a wasp because the web page was called "strange places to find a wasp nest" and had household objects surrounded by nests and things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely a *honeycomb* created by some species of honey bee.

A beekeeper (Jessie Brown) from New Mexico shared to her [blog](http://brownsdowntownbees.blogspot.com/2012/09/) the following photos of a "free form" bee hive some of her bees created:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Photo credit: Nina Dubois</sup>

In that instance (as well as the one mentioned [here](http://mudsongs.org/science-fiction-honey-comb/) and pictured below), the beekeeper moved some "[burr comb](http://blossomclub.com/get-rid-burr-comb/)" to a new location and the bees used that moved remnant piece to build a mound-like comb.

[image]

<sup>Photo credit: Phillip Cairns</sup>

Comment: That is pretty amazing. Great answer!